# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutPublicAccessBlock operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to implement PutPublicAccessBlock operation on S3 bucket inside my account. My code sample as below.

```
    s3Client.put_public_access_block(
    Bucket= name,
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
        'BlockPublicAcls': True,
        'IgnorePublicAcls': True,
        'BlockPublicPolicy': True,
        'RestrictPublicBuckets': True
    })
```

Even though lambda has **AmazonS3FullAccess** , but it's still not able to perform above action and getting `Access Denied`  error.

Any idea why is it happening?

Comment: The bucket name is correctly spelled and is definitely in an AWS account that your credentials are associated with? Is this AWS account part of an AWS Organization that has service control policies?

Comment: Yes bucket name is correctly spelled as I am doing other action on it. Yes, account is part of org. But I am trying to change things with lambda in my own account. I don't think that should give me an issue tbh

Comment: Service Control Policies at the org level could potentially be denying you permission for this S3 action.

Comment: can you add the full error message

Answer (score -1):

To do whatever you want in a bucket with lambda, you need to give permission to do that job in the lambda role and in the bucket policy.

```json
{
  "Id": "ExamplePolicy",
  "Version": "2022-07-02",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::<id_account>:role/<lambda_role_name>"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/) ([Español](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/))